# JQuery - Comparar 2 arrays em um each

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function pre() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "arquivo1.php",
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "arquivo2.php",
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data2) {

                    $.each(data.id, function(i, item) {

                        $( ".lado" ).prepend("<div id='" + data.id + "'><select class='select'></select></div>");

                        if (data.id == data2.id) {
                            $( ".select" ).append("<option'>" + data2.id + "</option>");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

São 2 ajax um dentro do outro que precisam comparar 2 tabelas diferentes e gerar a lista de selects e as opções dos selects, o if separa as opções que não são de tal select.

Comment: Seu problema é só comparar se os dois arrays são iguais?

Comment: não, preciso comparar e quando tiver item igual nos arrays ele lista, e são vários itens iguais com o mesmo id por exemplo, tipo 3 itens no "data1" iguais no "data2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você precisa de 2 `$.each`.
Assim:

```
    // primeiro laço 
    $.each(data, function(key_data_first, item_first) {

        // segundo laço
        $.each(data, function(key_data_second, item_second) {

            // cria o select
            $( ".lado" ).prepend("<div id='" + item_first.id + "'><select id='select_" + item_first.id + "' class='select'></select></div>");

            //insere as opções no select
            if (item_first.id == item_second.id) {
                $("#select_"+item_first.id).append("<option>" + item_second.id + "</option>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o que tiver dentro do `id` de cada `data` for um array, motivo para usar o `$.each`, pode fazer assim:

```
$.each(data.id, function(i, item) {
  $(".lado").prepend("<div id='" + data.id + "'><select class='select'></select></div>");
  if (item == data2.id[i]) {
    $(".select").append("<option'>" + data2.id + "</option>");
  }
});
```